# GetMaxPrivilegeDepthForUser Error when using the CRM Dynamics API

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am trying to integrate CRM Dynamics with Adobe Campaign, but I am getting an error.

Can anyone help me understand the meaning of this error:

> 'SecLib::GetMaxPrivilegeDepthForUser failed. Returned hr= -2147209463, User: a37d4ef0-7684-e511-8129-c4346bacefdc'

Comment: Please post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Give the service account user that you're using to authenticate with CRM's System Administrator role and make sure that user is also assigned to the most top-level business unit; if it doesn't work after that I would try creating a new administrator account from scratch.

Comment: thank you, your information was quite helpful but the issue turned out to be different in my case

Answer (score 0):

Our team was using the wrong company id or better to say organisation id for the CRM account. Using the correct value fixed our problem.